# Constant in a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

There exists a unique positive constant $c$ so that the limit
$$L=\lim_{x \to \infty}((x^3+x^2+x)^{1/5}−(x^3+x^2+1)^{1/5})x^c$$
exists and is nonzero. Then find $c$ and $L$. I got $c=1/5$ and $L=3/5$. Why is it wrong?

Comment: How did you get $c = 1/5$ and $L = 3/5$?

Comment: Consider rewriting those terms inside using the Binomial Theorem, then multiply the $x^c$ inside and see what that does...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Recall that, as $u \to 0$, **by the Taylor series expansion** you have
$$
(1+u)^{1/5}=1+\frac{u}{5}-\frac{2 u^2}{25}+\mathcal{O}(u^3)
$$ giving, as $x \to +\infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
(x^3+x^2+x)^{1/5}&=x^{3/5}\left(1+\frac {1}{x}+\frac {1}{x^2}\right)^{1/5}\\\\
&=x^{3/5}\left(1+\frac{1}{5x}+\frac{3 }{25x^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right),
\end{align}
$$ similarly
$$
\begin{align}
(x^3+x^2+1)^{1/5}&=x^{3/5}\left(1+\frac {1}{x}+\frac {1}{x^3}\right)^{1/5}\\\\
&=x^{3/5}\left(1+\frac{1}{5x}-\frac{2 }{25x^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right).
\end{align}
$$
Then, as $x \to +\infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
((x^3+x^2+x)^{1/5}−(x^3+x^2+1)^{1/5})x^c&=x^{3/5+c}\left(\frac{3 }{25x^2}+\frac{2 }{25x^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)\\\\
&=x^{3/5+c}\left(\frac{1}{5x^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right).
\end{align}
$$ and we should have
$$
\frac{3}{5}+c=2, \quad c=\frac{7}{5},\quad L=\frac{1}{5}.
$$